# Favicon not changing on XAMMP

Tags: html

I am using XAMPP This is the code for index.html, yet the favicon will still not change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you linked to the icon correctly? If so, you probably are facing a caching issue. Try `CTRL + F5`, holding `SHIFT` while clicking refresh, updating the favicon link (to something like `favicon.ico?v=1`), or simply waiting a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the "version of icon" , it is stored in the browser cache.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?1" type="image/x-icon">
```